# Are the actions of an artificial intelligence absolutely static?

Tags: python-3.6

I am creating an artificial intelligence that plays Plants vs Zombie. I have taken online courses to learn about the subject and would like to know if it is possible that the action list depending on the possibilities or they must be absolutely static? For exemple, a plant on squares of a grid

Comment: You better write the actions as object methods so they are not static. static would mean class methods. Then you can add methods (actions) to this object. Anyway you could add it to the class to so ... you can always add actions on events.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, since the values ​​of my inputLayer will change and it will change my actions possible. Instead of having them computed in the game and sent to my neural network, should I calculate them directly in my neural network?

Comment: Hum, you're not very specific.
I must add that a neural network has a fixed output dimension. Could be X,Y,Fight,Defend. Then you better have inteligent code to treat theses "orders". I just mean : YOU WANT A FIX OUTPUT FOR THE NN. Then play with adding methods according to the stuff. In code, you do what you want.

Comment: I made a plant vs zombie game and I want to create an artificial intelligence that will learn how to play the game. Taking into account, the money and the positioning of the plants in a grid. So, the possibilities of actions will change according to the chosen action. I just want to know if the possible actions should always remain the same or they can change? For example: When he puts a plant in a position X, Y, he will not be able to put one in this place time and as long as it is still alive.

Comment: Ok I get it ! You would like to make an array of possible actions, sorted, each one always at the same place (what you mean static) but sometime one action is not possible.
Put a mask as a member to each action object, "possible" or "not possible". Then each turn, the player will get a collection of actions to play some possible, some not. You can have that collection as a vector if you want. My advice : have actions as object and add to them as much members as you want, just show these members to the player so that he can access them. Hope this helps a little ...